# copy data from efs to efs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, copy, amazon-efs

I am trying to copy the data from one efs to other efs which are in both same region  and same AZ.  The source EFS1 has around 10 TB of data and uses key1 for data encryption and decryption . I created a new EFS with a different key key2 for    encryption and decryption .Now  i created a ec2 instance which  has access to both of these keys key1 and key2  and mounted  both efs1 and efs2.now when i am doing recursive copy from efs1 to efs2 , it is taking too much time . for just 10GB , it took almost 5 hours .As i said our efs total size is around 10 TB . So this recursive copy will take a lot of time . I used gnu/parallel  utility as well.  I used parallel 32 but still I could verify from nload that the transfer rate not exceeding 2 MB /se c .The process is very slow . Is there a quicker way here to copy the data from efs1 to efs2 , as both of them are in same region and same AZ. Just the key is different . any insights would really help.

tried following
cp -R /src /dest

Comment: What are the throughput settings on both EFS volumes? Do they have provisioned throughput? Burst throughput? If burst, are you exhausting the burst credits?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.